# What does "FOW" stand for in Just Cause 3?

Tags: terminology, just-cause-3

It seems to be the long-range weapon Di Ravello's forces have, but I don't remember anyone ever explaining exactly what it is or even what "FOW" stands for. In my head, I've been thinking of it as the "Freaking Owesome Weapon," but I vaguely suspect that's not quite right.

Comment: Sounds like a knockoff version of the widely used [TOW missile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BGM-71_TOW)

Comment: I think this is BFG-9000 all over again. https://www.reddit.com/r/JustCause/comments/3w0u4o/what_does_fow_stand_for/

Comment: F*cking Overpowered Weapon

Answer (score 5):

Flames Of War. It's said a few times by Ravello, he's referencing his faction's capabilities. Each time you take a region's flame of war, the rebels work it into something Rico can use in the field.

Answer (score 4):

Although the actual definition is never revealed within the game, a weapon that is classified as a *[FOW](http://justcause.wikia.com/wiki/FOW)* is a weapon that has been infused with *[Bavarium](http://justcause.wikia.com/wiki/Bavarium)*.

> Any weapon infused with Bavarium is classed as a "FOW" weapon by the Medici Military. The exact definition of "FOW" is never revealed in the game. It is sometimes pronounced as an abbreviation, whilst at other times it is pronounced as an acronym. The letter "W" likely stands for Weapon.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming it means Forward Operating Weapon, as FOB means, in real military lingo, Forward Operating Base.

Answer (score -1):

It might mean Futuristic Operative Weaponry. As the thunderbird FOW gun is futuristic. And the M488 is a stable bavarium nucelar weapon and the airstrike gun is a standard piece of weaponary. (I wouldnt classify airstrike as an FOW) yet the DLC guns do not count for a FOW. Only the Eden spark (Rico calls it sparky) is a powerful and acuurate FOW. It is more deadlier the falco maxime's bavarium warheads.

Answer (score -2):

Final Offensive Weapon-perhaps because it's the last weapon before you can get into the centcom!as well as the last best chance to take out the toughest places or opponents after trying everything else? Or it could be an inside joke by the delves meaning Fu** off world,or maybe Forget Other Weapon's! LOL goodluck!

Answer (score -3):

Faction Orbital Weapon is what I read on the Steam forums.

Comment: Would be good to link the thread from the forums and quote it so that the source is known and can be checked.

Answer (score -4):

Family of Weapon, I believe. Could be wrong but seems to match

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have a source for this, would you?

Answer (score -4):

My thought is Future Ordinance Weapon?  Or something else Ordinance Weapon.